# "No enum constant org.apache.orc.CompressionKind.ZSTD" When Insert Data to ORC Compress ZSTD Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc, apache-tez, zstd

I have created a table in hive `3.1.3` as below;

```
Create external table test_tez_orc_zstd
( 
Id bigint
)stored as orc
Tblproperties(orc.compress=zstd)
Location '...'
```

It is created, and then I wanted to insert one row;

```
Insert into test_tez_orc_zstd
Select 1
```

Then it throwed following error;

```
No enum constant org.apache.orc.CompressionKind.ZSTD
```

Hive is configured to use Tez.

If I do same thing for `parquet` compress `zstd` it works.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ROOT CAUSE:**

Apache Hive version `3.1.3` uses `orc` version `1.5.8`, please see [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/rel/release-3.1.3/pom.xml#L186).  `zstd` decompression has been supported in `orc` starting from `1.6.0`; https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ORC-363.

You can see `1.5.8` enum constants [here](https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/rel/release-1.5.8/java/core/src/java/org/apache/orc/CompressionKind.java#L26) and `1.6.0` [here](https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/rel/release-1.6.0/java/core/src/java/org/apache/orc/CompressionKind.java#L26). So, in this case we can say that Hive `3.1.3` does not support `Tblproperties(orc.compress=zstd)`.

---

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

In Hive, `orc` version has been upgraded to above `1.6.0` in release `4.0.0-alpha-1` here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-23553.

This might be challenging, but you can backport related commits on top of release tag `3.1.3`, then build the project and replace the related jars in Hive's library.

Please note that not only `orc` dependencies are in Hive's library directly, but also they are included into some of the fat jars such as `hive-exec`.

So, steps should be as follows;

1. Clone `hive` and checkout to release tag `3.1.3`.
2. Backport the commits that upgrade `orc` to the desired version.
3. Build the project `mvn clean package -DskipTests`.
4. `grep` `orc` in hive library where you installed hive to see which `orc` dependencies directly in the classpath, and which fat jars have `orc` classes.
5. Replace the jars that you identified in the previous step.

The challenging part is that `orc` upgrade commits can be pretty big, and there might be conflicts.